# ConstraintLayout - Aligning two views to center vertically against another view

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

[image]

I'm trying to center two views vertically on a third view.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/vh_buisnesspost_buisness_preview"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_circle_preview_border"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/vh_buisnesspost_buisness_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Buisness Name"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlackFont"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/vh_buisnesspost_buisness_preview"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/vh_buisnesspost_buisness_preview"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/vh_buisnesspost_date_posted"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/vh_buisnesspost_date_posted"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="2 mins ago"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/vh_buisnesspost_buisness_preview"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/vh_buisnesspost_buisness_preview"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/vh_buisnesspost_buisness_name"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"/>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/vh_buisnesspost_post_type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text=" \u2022 Restaurant"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/vh_buisnesspost_date_posted"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/vh_buisnesspost_buisness_preview"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/vh_buisnesspost_buisness_name"/>
```

However when I do this, it leaves an unwanted space between the two views.

What can I do to center these two views, to the third view?

Comment: You want the two textviews to be without any gap?

Comment: Yes, I've also tried using a horizontal guideline, but adding the attributes: "constraintTop_toBottomOf" do not do anything to guidelines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"` to the first TextView to change the style of the chain. The default style is `spread` which will leave a space between the chained views to spread them equally. The `packed` style will pack them together with a default bias of 0.5 which is what you want.

EDIT for the updated question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/vh_buisnesspost_buisness_preview"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_circle_preview_border"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/vh_buisnesspost_buisness_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Buisness Name"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlackFont"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/vh_buisnesspost_buisness_preview"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/vh_buisnesspost_buisness_preview"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/vh_buisnesspost_date_posted"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/vh_buisnesspost_date_posted"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="2 mins ago"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/vh_buisnesspost_buisness_preview"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/vh_buisnesspost_buisness_preview"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/vh_buisnesspost_buisness_name"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/vh_buisnesspost_post_type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text=" \u2022 Restaurant"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/vh_buisnesspost_date_posted"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/vh_buisnesspost_date_posted"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/vh_buisnesspost_date_posted"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What would I do about other textviews? Adding the chainStyle seems to center one of them https://i.imgur.com/woTdXOi.png

Comment: You can constrain it vertically to the `vh_buisnesspost_date_posted` TextView. I updated the answer.

Comment: Ah I see. Perfect, thanks for explaining everything.

Comment: I made a typo in the very last constraint ('Top_toTop**m**Of'). Make sure to correct that :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]Wrapping the two text view inside a linear layout does the trick

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/vh_buisnesspost_buisness_preview"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/vh_buisnesspost_buisness_preview"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/vh_buisnesspost_buisness_preview">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vh_buisnesspost_buisness_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:text="Buisness Name"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vh_buisnesspost_date_posted"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:text="2 mins ago"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I want to achieve this without an unnecessary layout.

Answer (score 0):

try this sample it dosn't require other `ViewGroup` only `ConstraintLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_circle_preview_border"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:text="Buisness Name"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/image"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="2 mins ago"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/image"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/textView1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView1" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```